# Change cart icon in luma theme

Tags: magento2

I have added background image with

```
.minicart-wrapper .action.showcart::before
```

when we remove `content: '\e611';`   it also remove newly added background image.
anyone help me.
[image]

Comment: Put background on anchor and set height and width to that anchor.

Comment: just have content like so,  `content: ' '`